# How to add more identifier colors to Android IDE Studio - Android

Tags: android, ide

I've recently started to use Android IDE Studio and programming in Java. But as first impression of this IDE I see a lot of gray. Programming in C (Visual Studio) I had every variable with a color, types with same color but with Bolt, functions(methods) with a red color with Bolt and so on. It's possible to do something like this also in Android IDE Studio?

As example this is a part of code:

```
            DatagramSocket ds = null;
            ds = new DatagramSocket(UDP_SERVER_PORT);
            ds = new DatagramSocket();
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.4.1");
            DatagramPacket dp;
            dp = new DatagramPacket(udpMsg.getBytes(), udpMsg.length(), serverAddr, UDP_SERVER_PORT);
            ds.send(dp);
```

I'd like to see class names in a color, methods in another, variables and types in another and same for wrappers. Maybe it's correct to have all gray, but my eye is so used to colors and I've difficulty to read code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the theme of Android studio, you can do so by
`File->Settings->Editor->Colors & Fonts->` In scheme name select Darcula and apply to see a awesome dark background theme editor
On mac `Android Studio -> Preferences ->`

You can find themes in various places on the internet, as well as on GitHub. [Editor's note: the website previously linked here containing colorthemes has switched owners and has been replaced with spam]

Once you have downloaded the .jar file, go to File -> Import Settings... and choose the file downloaded.